# Template Class Inside Template Class - Different Parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, iterator

Is it possible to create a template class inside a template class like the following

```
// Container.h
template <typename T>
class Container
{
private:
  using iterator = Iterator<Node<T>>;
  using const_iterator = Iterator<const Node<T>>;

  // Node struct to hold data.
  template <typename T>
  struct Node
  {
    T data_;
  };

public:
  // Templated iterator for const or non-const.
  template <typename NodeType>
  class Iterator
  {
  private:
    NodeType* node_;
  
  public:
    Iterator();
  };
};

#include "Container.tpp"
```

So here I declare a template for an iterator that takes in a `NodeType` which is different from the `T` that the container class template takes.

If this is possible to do, how do I implemenet the `Iterator()` inside a different file? Something like

```
// Container.tpp
template <typename T>
LinkedList<T>::LinkedListIterator<NodeType>::Iterator()
{
  // Implementation ...
}
```

This does not seem right since I do not have access to the `NodeType`. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: A "template class inside a template class" would mean, for example, that a container of `int` needs nodes of `int` as well as nodes of `char`, nodes of `float`, nodes of `std::vector< std::map<int, std::string> >`, etc. That is probably not what you meant. Perhaps you want to rewrite your question to explain what you want instead of trying to explain via code?

Comment: @JaMiT I think songuanyao already answered it.

Comment: I think the next person with the same question would skip reading that answer because of how the question is worded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define it as

```
template <typename T>        // for the enclosing class template
template <typename NodeType> // for the member template
Container<T>::Iterator<NodeType>::Iterator()
{
  // Implementation ...
}
```

---

BTW: The member class template `Node` can't use the same template parameter name `T` as the outer class template.

Comment: Ok that makes sense for the iterator. For the `Node` though should I just remove that template declaration line?

Comment: @nick2225 If you want it to be template itself, just change to use another template parameter name (as `Iterator` does). If it doesn't have to be template, just remove the line.

Comment: @nick2225 As a non-template class, `Node` could use template parameter `T` of outer class template too.